# ReactJS App Created with create-react-app on Edge 104

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I have react app that is completely functional when you run it with npm run and open it in Edge. But as soon as I build & open it in Edge Version 104.0.1293.47 (Official build) (64-bit) I get it opened in Legacy mode (IE mode). It's not even deployed in organization  intranet, but to AWS EKS.
[IE mode warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVC02.png)
I have tried to change browserList in packages.json, but to no avail...

[image]

```
"browserslist": {
"production": [
  "last 3 chrome version",
  "last 3 firefox version",
  "last 3 safari version",
  "last 3 edge version"
],
"development": [
  "last 1 chrome version",
  "last 1 firefox version",
  "last 1 safari version"
]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot, I could see that your site is loading in an intranet zone with IE-7 compatibility mode.

It is not related to something on your site.

I would suggest trying to visit any other intranet site in the Edge browser and see whether it also gets loaded into IE mode.

It could be possible that the Edge browser is controlled by your organization and they have applied some group policies that is loading this site to the IE mode.

I would suggest visiting `edge://policy/` in the Edge browser and seeing which policies are applied there.

Check whether the policy below is configured.

[Send all intranet sites to Internet Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies#configure-all-intranet-sites)

Or, try to check whether your site is added to the Enterprise mode site list file.

[Configure using the Configure the Enterprise Mode Site List policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies#configure-using-the-configure-the-enterprise-mode-site-list-policy)

It could also be possible that due to some IE browser group policies, the site is loading into IE mode, compatibility mode-7. So you could also check those policies.